# Pandas - to_csv() and from_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been working `to_csv()`/`read_csv()` to read/write a data frame a user works with in an applet, where one of the columns is a `datetime.datetime` object, and it seems like `to_csv` automatically converts the datetimes to strings. Is this correct? If so, is there a way to "preserve" the dates as `datetime` rather than them being converted to strings? I've read through the documentation, and I can't seem to find the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this? What information is being lost when it's converted to a string? What would you prefer it be written as?

Comment: So, I'd like to add an option to graph date vs. value for any read .csv file, and according to my professor you can only do that with datetimes, not strings. Is this not true?

Comment: The `parse_dates` argument in `read_csv` should allow you to read dates back into python objects. Or you can do as the answer suggests if you are only using the csv for serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve the exact structure of a DataFrame, complete with data types, check out the pickle module, which "serializes" any python object to disk and reloads it back into a python environment.

Use `pd.to_pickle` instead of `pd.to_csv`, optionally with a `compression` argument (see [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)):

```
# Save to pickle
df.to_pickle('pickle-file.pkl')
# Pickle with compression
df.to_pickle('pickle-file.pkl.gz', compression='gzip')

# Load pickle from disk
df = pd.read_pickle('pickle-file.pkl')
# or...
df = pd.read_pickle('pickle-file.pkl.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Comment: What does the ``compression`` parameter do?

Comment: It compresses your data, allowing it to take up less space on disk :) more details in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html